# Reproduce an image or shape using only type and words

Tags: canvas, cpu-word

I'm tasked with building an app that would recreate an image using words and type alone.
For a very rough example of what the end result might be
http://fineartamerica.com/featured/manhattan-new-york-typographic-map-michael-tompsett.html

My first question is
Could such an application be entirely built in the front end using Canvas?

If so, which canvas library would work best, Kinetic.js or Easel.js?

Are there any CC javascript libraries that might help with some of the functionality?

If not Canvas, what other possible front end solutions might work? (no flash, silverlight, etc

Comment: Is that a realistic example? For something like that, you'd need to first identify the image, hit some data source for neighborhood information (and maybe polygons) if it is a land mass, and go from there...is that what you have in mind? or a more granular approach where: this 10x10 pixel square looks (by some pattern matching system you'd implement) like the character V, so replace the image with this character...repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is very possible in Canvas. If you don't want to use a plugin, canvas is a good bet, but SVG is a good bet too, since there's no performance issues involved and SVG already has some built in event handlers to help you.

I wouldn't bother using Kinetic or Easel unless you are very comfortable using them for your project. If you don't know which one is better, *you are not comfortable enough with them to either for the project*. Learn more about them first, but I'd encourage instead going solo if you plan on a future of canvas development and this isn't just a one-off canvas project.

SVG has similar libraries, such as Raphael.

Making a canvas or SVG app that renders text that you can then resize, rotate, and move is not particularly hard. Giving a bunch of words and a shape and having it done automatically, however, would be something else entirely and isn't really a canvas problem, its more of just a general topological program that would be the same on any platform, and non-trivial to implement.

Comment: thanks. Agreed about it being 'non-trivial to implement' but there are a few MIT licensed projects out there that might be a starting point. As to NOT using Kinetic or Easel, I partially disagree. As long as I know the basics in canvas, what better way to master either framework?

Comment: Well, its a question of whether you want to master a framework or master Canvas. IF you have the time, I'd go with pure canvas, and if you don't have much time, either one will will do (Kinetic is more powerful though, which means a little harder to learn but can do more things than easel)